# How to set pivotX to right edge in xml

Tags: android, animator

How to set `pivotX` to right `edge` in xml. In `res/anim` it is possible by setting the value to "100%", but how it make in `"res/animator"` ?

res/animator/slide.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueFrom="0.f"
            android:valueTo="1.f"
            android:duration="@integer/durationAnimate"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate" />

        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="500"
            android:propertyName="pivotY"
            android:valueFrom="1.0"
            android:valueTo="1.0"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
```

I need it in animator because, I make picture browser when there is random animation.
Animation implementation by:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_right_out)
            .replace(R.id.mainActivityNew_fragmentAnimate, FotoFragment.newInstance(itemsController.nextItem()))
            .commit();
```

In `res/anim/...` can not rotate fragment in axis (x or y), therefore, I would prefer to accomplish `in res/animator/...`. Unfortunately, I can in that make one type of animation and in that the second type of animation /